# Splitting test/training data for scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was given some starter code, but I'm not sure how to split it up when calling train_test_split (which I was explicitly told to use). Essentially, where does it come into play when I'm already given an X_train, Y_train, and X_test split?

The starter code looks like so:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv('./train_preprocessed.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('./test_preprocessed.csv')
X_train = train_df.drop("Survived",axis=1)
Y_train = train_df["Survived"]
X_test = test_df.drop("PassengerId",axis=1).copy()
print(train_df[train_df.isnull().any(axis=1)])

##SVM
svc = SVC()
svc.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
acc_svc = round(svc.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
print("svm accuracy is:", acc_svc)
```

I need to change the acc_svc variable to be using X_test and Y_test, however. X_test is given to us, but how do I come up with a Y_test? I know the Y_test should correspond to labels, and I'm having some size mismatching going on when I attempt to do so. Should be a simple question, anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test_preprocessed.csv shouldn't be used to check your model performance. Split your train_df using train_test_split() in scikit-learn into train and validation datasets. You have to check your model performance on validation dataset i.e. y of validation. Please refer to: [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: So the "X_test = test_df.drop("PassengerId",axis=1).copy()" line was something given to me from the get go. Is that what you're referring to? if so, any idea why the test data set was used here?

Comment: PassengerId is unique variable and doesn't have an predictive power. So, you have remove that in your all your dataframes i.e. train,validation, test. The test dataset should be considered as an unseen dataset and should be used to predict the y values. You cannot measure the performance on that test set. So, what I was referring to was - `X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(train_df, y, test_size=0.2)`. Now use y_validation to measure your model prediction performance.

Comment: And by 'y', would you be referring to just the training data set for the label? I.e. "Survived"

Comment: Yes, 'y' would have the target variable just as you did: `y = train_df["Survived"]`

Comment: So this answer seems to work. Getting a 72% accuracy with my test sets (which is weirdly higher than my training sets). Ignoring that, I'll accept this answer, but if you don't mind I might bug you about one more thing. 

So I understand that PassengerId doesn't hold any predictive power. It looks like it was already removed from the training dataset, so that's why I can just include the training dataset as is in my test_train_split? Then additionally, all that y=train_df["Survived] is doing is creating a df of the same dimension but with only my labels, and that's what I'm using to train?

Comment: Yes, if you don't have PassengerId in train, validation datasets, that's good to use as is. Make sure that you don't have any variable that uniquely identifies each row in your train_df. Yes, you have to capture target label in 'y' to split and train on the y_train.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, you have to understand and clarify your target variable. Your "*Y_test*" seems to be your already existed "Y_pred" variable, which seems to correspond to the "Survived" label (in your test set). However, although you are dropping it from the "X_train" so that you can use it as a target, you don't seem to do the same in the "Y_train", where instead you are dropping "PassengerId".
- Another basic concept here is that your dataset is already split into train-test subsets (your CSV files). I assume that your test set has already one less column compared to the train set, and that should be the "Survived" variable as a continuation from the train CSV file. Otherwise, you should drop it to avoid mismatching and keep that as your test target variable. You don't have to come up with a *"Y_test"*, the result from your equation *"Y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)"* will give you the "Y_test" which would be the result of the "Y_pred".
- One possible reason you get size mismatching is that the number of columns (x-axis) in your train set is not equal with that of the test set.
- If you want to split into [train/test subsets based on Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) you would first merge your CSV files, then do the data analysis in the merged dataset, and finally, do the split. One way to keep track of these changes and maintain the same original size of the train-test split could be to keep key-value pairs originated from the train-test merge. One way to do that could be via the [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), using the parameter *"keys"*.

Incorporating the above, one recommended simple solution might be:

```
# reading csv files
train_df = pd.read_csv('./train_preprocessed.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('./test_preprocessed.csv')

# merge train and test sets
merged_data = pd.concat([train_df, test_df], keys=[0,1])

# data preprocessing can take place in the below assigned variable
# here also you could do feature engineering etc.
# e.g. check null values for all dataset
print(merged_data[merged_data.isnull().any(axis=1)])

# now you can eject the train and test sets, using the key-value pairs from the train-test merge
X_train = merged_data.xs(0)
X_test = merged_data.xs(1)

# setting up predictors - target
X= X_train.loc[:, X_train.columns!="Survived"]
y= X_train.loc[:, "Survived"]

# train-test split
# If train_size is None, it will be set to 0.25 based on the documentation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

##SVM
svc = SVC()
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)
acc_svc = round(svc.score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)
print("svm accuracy is:", acc_svc)
```

In my opinion, after understanding the above you could further estimate and compare your model's performance using the [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) function, in a way @SunilG mentions. For e.g. a 3-fold (CV=3) cross validation, you could:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(svc, X_train, y_train.values, cv=3, scoring='accuracy')
```

If you do not want to proceed to the above and you want to be close to your starter code, then you should delete your 5th line of code and I suppose it would run (if your test set does not include your target variable, otherwise drop it). However in this case you would not be able to split your train-test on your own, since it is already split, hence the title of your main question/post should be altered.

Comment: Already accepted an answer but this was super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You can upvote the answer in case you found it useful. I hope you resolved your issue.